# Magento cron job stuck sometines

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.9

We are having 1 strange issue with cron in magento 1.9.3.

We set cron to run once per minute. It is working proper when we set. But it automatic stops working and cron set to once per 15 minutes on server.

Is there any issue with admin config or this is problem of hosting server?

cron command is `php -f Path/To/File/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`
Also tried using cron.sh but still have same issue..

Please advice..

Comment: Check your cron settings under `System -> Configuration -> System`. On a side note, always use cron.sh, it makes sure you have no more than on cron process running at a time.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler, it will help you  in your debugging efforts.

Comment: @MladenIlić Thanks for your time..  You can check admin cron setting on https://ibb.co/dyHdPn. And we also tried /bin/sh path/to/magento/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 but still we are havving same issue

Comment: @TomS Thanks for reply. We checked that extension but Our client don't want any extra extension